# Multiple themes in QGIS defaulting to first theme

Tags: qgis, qgis-print-layouts

I've been trying to use the themes options in QGIS.

In the window mode they work just quite well and layer format changes.

[image: Themes in QGIS window]

But when I go to the layout print menu the themes show up but it keeps defaulting back to the first theme.

[image: QGIS Layout]

My question is, Is there a way to different themes in the layout window or have I missed a step.

I suspect it's a bug in QGIS - I'm using Version 3.10.

Comment: Hm, I'm using 3.10, and whenever I check "Follow map theme" and change the theme, the map content change accordingly. In my case only "Follow map theme" is checked, not "Lock layers" and "Lock styles for layers".

Comment: I tried only use "Follow map theme" - Same result happens. Maybe I'll have to try it again with a new work space

Comment: why (in your last screenshot) is **follow map theme** unchecked ? it doesn't seem logical knowing what's your aim ... i don't see how this would work in that case. with this checkbox left unchecked i suppose the two others options (lock layers and lock styles) override any selection you made in **follow map theme** (imho)

Comment: QGIS doesn't let you chose both "Follow Map Theme" and Lock layers. It's one or the other. Not sure why. Tried all possible combinations and got the same result.

Comment: Why would you like to check both? It's enough with "Follow map theme" checked. The map content changes accordingly with the chosen map theme in 3.10.

Comment: I tried this with a new layout with less layers - it seemed to be working ok. It's just this work space it seems to default back to the top style. Who knows.... If I replicate the error again I'll post it with steps to replicate the error.